# Convert ts field to seconds

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, postgresql

I need to convert the ts field to a `floating point number expressed in seconds`

```
 |              ts               | user_id |   object_id |
 +-------------------------------+---------+-------------+
 | 2016-08-12 15:13:34.898779+01 |      12 |       5     |
```

The same format that can be achieved with

```
   import time
   ts = time.time()
   print ts #1507023571.12
```

So, my question is How can I convert the ts field?

Comment: Could you please add your expected output sample too in code tags?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I need to use the ts field in postgres as ts field in zadd. So I am looking for the converted value that will be accepted for redis sorted set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `epoch`:

```
t=# select extract(epoch from now()), now();
    date_part     |              now
------------------+-------------------------------
 1507024254.74876 | 2017-10-03 09:50:54.748764+00
(1 row)
```

**edit**

use smth like: `select extract(epoch from ts) ts from reputation_log`

Comment: thanks. To make this query for all ts rows? Not working something like this `select extract(epoch from (select  ts from reputation_log));`